# Is there a way to get notifications whenever something in my server crashes? (like apache2, mysql, ect' that cause the website not to work)

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have a website on a server I created on Amazon AWS (Ubuntu).

A few days ago my "mysql" stopped working due to insufficient RAM. I got a call from my boss reguarding this problem and tried to fix it (by expanding the RAM on my.cnf file).

Then a few days later I got the same issue, and we decided to get a server with more RAM.

A few days later apache2 stopped working for some reason, and I don't remember what was the problem there, but it was solved.

**The bottom line is:**

I want to find a way to get notifications in situations like this via email/SMS text messages or in any other way, that will give me instant updates about "errors" on the server, so I won't get surprise calls from my boss and know immediately about issues on the website so there won't be situations that the website is down for too long (that cause us to loose sales ect').

Comment: Any monitoring system can do this.

Comment: Any special suggestion to a specific monitoring system?

Comment: No, picking a monitoring system is your job :)

Comment: I'd suggest [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) for this. Easy, lightweight and will do what you need.